# How can I find the difference between two times (hh:mm) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, time

I have a shapefile of crime reports that includes the time a call was received and the time officers arrived on scene.  I want to create response times from the difference in these two values.  I know QGIS has support for the difference between dates, but I need the difference between two times in hh:mm format.  Is there a way to do this in QGIS specifically? I am running QGIS 2.0 standalone version.

Comment: Are the two times stored in string/text fields just like "hh:mm"? I'm curious about the field type because it really determines how the field calculator needs to be used.

Comment: They are currently string fields.

Comment: You can check out a sample of the dataset at https://github.com/chadbunn/SLO-Crime/blob/master/timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to do this in QGIS, but I was able to do it simply with Excel and edit my .csv file with a new response time category. I'm sure there is a way to do it in QGIS but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the hour() field calculator function with a nested age() function:

`hour(age("FIELD1","FIELD2"))`

That should output the difference in hours. But you might have to re-create your input field  as Date type and format them like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` if not already.

I'm not sure if you can use more nested *Conversion* functions like `tointerval()` or `hour()`/`minute()`/`second()` in the above expression if field calculator in QGIS doesn't recognize the fields you input because they might be *strings*.

[image: hour() and age() function for qgis field calculator]

Comment: I am going to give this a shot since I have a year and date field.

Comment: OK I am having trouble creating new date fields that combine the date with the time_recei, and another with the date and time_arriv.  I am unfamiliar with how to create a date type column in QGIS but I see that it is possible.  I have put a sample of the dataset at https://github.com/chadbunn/SLO-Crime/blob/master/timestamp in case you want to check it out.  Any help or ideas would be very helpful!

Comment: @cbunn Sure, having a peek.

Comment: If you want the shapefile I can email it to you.

Comment: @SaulDon I had a thought that I could convert my hh:mm fields to the minute equivalent (i.e. hh*60+mm) to get a total minute count and then derive response times in minutes.  Is there a good way to create this formula?